# "Chrome failed to start" A Specific watir-webdriver? Issue (chromedriver installed)

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu, watir-webdriver

I run my Ruby script

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome #<--- OFFENDING LINE
```

It stalls in terminal and I get this error message about 25 seconds later:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8939d7cd5bf39b7e7a36240b614985bc

Also, when I run `google-chrome` from terminal I get this error message:

`[22016:22016:1017/135305:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(260)] Gtk: cannot open display:`

And when I run `xhost +` I get `xhost:  unable to open display ""`

---

System Information:

I believe I have installed Chrome, however, I'm not sure, but these lines were executed:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'`

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`

chromedriver is installed and is located in `/usr/local/bin` and was installed using the following command lines:

`wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_linux64.zip && sudo unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/;`

`watir-webdriver (0.9.3)` shows up in my list of gems

`ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [x86_64-linux]`

---

### Question:

Why do I get [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8939d7cd5bf39b7e7a36240b614985bc) error, and how can I fix it?

---

<sup>I can provide more details if requested.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Chromedriver 2.9 is very old. You want Chromedriver 2.24 right now. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

It looks like Chromedriver can't access the instance of Chrome. Here's an example of how the Watir team does it via command line: 
https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/support/travis.sh#L13-L28

Comment: I will try this, but I am under the impression that my server is GUI-less and so cannot open this GUI-browser;however, I read recently on Hacker News that Google is developing a GUI-less browser. See [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11839303).

Comment: Yeah, I installed 2.24 and got the same error in the OP gist.

Comment: The error in the gist says Chromedriver 2.9. If you are still getting that error after installing 2.24, do a "which chromedriver" to see where it is picking up the ancient version and update it.

Comment: I execute `rvm use ruby 2.0 ; ruby /lib/form_connect.rb`, then `Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648` pops up in green, cursor stalls for ~30 seconds, then this error appears: `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)`

Comment: I know, I still get the same _error_ though, but with a different version listed. Actually, today the error is different: `/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb:158:in rescue in rbuf_fill': Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)`. Running `chromedriver -v` returns `ChromeDriver 2.24.417424`